# Multiple friend class in C++

Tags: c++, object, oop, inheritance

Is there a way to give private access to all the class that inherit from a base class

Example

```
class Text
{
public:
    const char* GetText()
    {
        return text;
    }
private:
    const char* text;

    friend class Shape;
};

class Shape
{
    int Sides;
};

class Square : public Shape
{

};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{

};
```

Here how can you give private access to Square and Rectangle

Comment: If you want all derived class to have access to a base class member, then you make that member `protected` instead of `private`. This is the specific use case of these access specifiers.

Comment: `int Sides;` : this will be private as well

Comment: I have no idea what should be the relation between class `Text` and `Shape`, because the latter and it's inheritants don't even use `Text`??? It's completely unclear what you want to do, and why. [Edit] your question and elaborate please!

Answer (score 2):

Make a `protected` accessor in the base class; when you want to access `text`, don't access it directly, but use the accessor instead.

```
class Shape
{
    int Sides;

protected:
    static const char*& AccessTheText(Text& object)
    {
        return object.text;
    }
};

class Square : public Shape
{
    void do_stuff()
    {
        Text object;
        ...
        std::cout << AccessTheText(object);
    }
};
```